# Java: equalsIgnoreCase + message.startswith?

Tags: java, ignore-case

Got a Question:

How can i combine message.equalsIgnoreCase and message.startswith() ?

i.e:

```
if (message.startsWith("!spoiler")) {
    String name = sender;
    if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase(ownerchannel)){
        try {
            String spoiler = message.split("!spoiler ")[1];
            sendMessage(channel, "/timeout "+name+" 1");
            if(englishmode == true){
                sendMessage(channel, "Spoiler from "+name+" deleted. Click at 'message deleted' above to read it!");
            }else{
                sendMessage(channel, "Spoiler von "+name+" wurde zensiert. Wer diesen lesen möchte klickt einfach oben auf 'message deleted'.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

in my code above,  !spoiler xyz will trigger it but !Spoiler xyz wont. how can i combine it to ma tch startswith + ignorecase?

Comment: Are you trying to do an AND or OR?  Do you want to find matches where the name and the message match your criteria or find when either the name or the message matches your criteria?

Comment: i want the code to react to "!spoiler " as ignorecase and hte message itself should remain as it is. :-)

Comment: See Reimeus' answer then.

Comment: message.regionMatches...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`toLowerCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29)

```
if (message.toLowerCase().startsWith("!spoiler")) {
```

Comment: And this wouldn't set the whole message to lowercase when i output the "message"-string?

Comment: you're not changing the message String itself since `toLowerCase` returns a new `String` (Strings are immutable)

Comment: This answer is wrong. If you look at the implementation of `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` you will discover that you need to compare **both** lowercase and uppercase versions of the Strings before you can conclusively return `false`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38947571/14731 for an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert (a copy of) the string to all lower-case, then just use .startsWith() with the lower-case version of what it's checking for.

Answer (score 0):

`split` requires a regular expression.  You would have to use the regular expression for the case you don't care about.

```
message.split("![Ss]poiler");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to combine both:

```
if (message.startsWith("!spoiler") && !sender.equalsIgnoreCase(ownerchannel)) {
        String name = sender;
            try {
                String spoiler = message.split("!spoiler ")[1];
                sendMessage(channel, "/timeout "+name+" 1");
                if(englishmode == true){
                    sendMessage(channel, "Spoiler from "+name+" deleted. Click at 'message deleted' above to read it!");
                }else{
                    sendMessage(channel, "Spoiler von "+name+" wurde zensiert. Wer diesen lesen möchte klickt einfach oben auf 'message deleted'.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

    }
```