# How do I ignore case when using startsWith and endsWith in Java?

Tags: java, string, case-insensitive, startswith, ends-with

Here's my code:

```
public static void rightSel(Scanner scanner,char t)
{
  /*if (!stopping)*/System.out.print(": ");
    if (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
     String orInput = scanner.nextLine;
        if (orInput.equalsIgnoreCase("help")
        {
            System.out.println("The following commands are available:");
            System.out.println("    'help'      : displays this menu");
            System.out.println("    'stop'      : stops the program");
            System.out.println("    'topleft'   : makes right triangle alligned left and to the top");
            System.out.println("    'topright'  : makes right triangle alligned right and to the top");
            System.out.println("    'botright'  : makes right triangle alligned right and to the bottom");
            System.out.println("    'botleft'   : makes right triangle alligned left and to the bottom");
        System.out.println("To continue, enter one of the above commands.");
     }//help menu
     else if (orInput.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")
     {
        System.out.println("Stopping the program...");
            stopping    = true;
     }//stop command
     else
     {
        String rawInput = orInput;
        String cutInput = rawInput.trim();
        if (
```

I'd like to allow the user some leeway as to how they can enter the commands, things like: Top Right, top-right, TOPRIGHT, upper left, etc.
To that end, I'm trying to, at that last `if (`, check if `cutInput` starts with either "top" or "up" AND check if `cutInput` ends with either "left" or "right", all while being case-insensitive. Is this at all possible?

The end goal of this is to allow the user to, in one line of input, pick from one of four orientations of a triangle. This was the best way I could think of to do that, but I'm still quite new to programming in general and might be over complicating things. If I am, and it turns there's a simpler way, please let me know.

Comment: Use `command.toLowerCase().startsWith("up")` and `command.toLowerCase().endsWith("right")`.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Like this:

```
aString.toUpperCase().startsWith("SOMETHING");
aString.toUpperCase().endsWith("SOMETHING");
```

Comment: Will `.toUpperCase()` work even if the string contains non-alphabetic characters? Also, do you know if these can be combined in a conditional using logic(al?) operators?

Comment: @MataoGearsky It'll work, of course. The non-alphabetic characters will simply be ignored by `toUpperCase()`. And sure enough, the above can be combined with logical operators (and why not? they're just boolean expressions.)

Comment: This answer is wrong. If you look at the implementation of `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` you will discover that you need to compare both lowercase and uppercase versions of the Strings before you can conclusively return `false`. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/38947571/14731.

Comment: And its performance is not optimal. What if your `aString` is huge?

Comment: Will not work for other locales.
"edit".toUpperCase() is "EDİT" in Turkish (Note the dot on the capital i)
So "editThis".toUpperCase().startsWith("EDIT") returns false with a turkish locale.

Comment: Ma non è vero!  ~Michael

Answer (score 52):

The accepted answer is wrong. If you look at the implementation of `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` you will discover that you need to compare **both** lowercase and uppercase versions of the Strings before you can conclusively return `false`.

Here is my own version, based on http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/CaseinsensitivecheckifaStringstartswithaspecifiedprefix.htm:

```
/**
 * String helper functions.
 *
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 */
public final class Strings
{
    /**
     * @param str    a String
     * @param prefix a prefix
     * @return true if {@code start} starts with {@code prefix}, disregarding case sensitivity
     */
    public static boolean startsWithIgnoreCase(String str, String prefix)
    {
        return str.regionMatches(true, 0, prefix, 0, prefix.length());
    }

    public static boolean endsWithIgnoreCase(String str, String suffix)
    {
        int suffixLength = suffix.length();
        return str.regionMatches(true, str.length() - suffixLength, suffix, 0, suffixLength);
    }

    /**
     * Prevent construction.
     */
    private Strings()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that only because of the Georgian alphabet?

Comment: @bphilipnyc Correct. That is one example mentioned by the `String` source-code, but we have no idea whether it is the only one. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: In addition this method avoids lowercasing and copying parts of the string that would never be checked.

Comment: Side note: Spring Framework aligns with Gili's answer, too: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.java#L330

Comment: This is a concrete example for why we need to compare both lowercase and uppercase versions : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15518878/1546137

Comment: Note: please format it as Java. It's nor C++ or C#.

Comment: @Aleksander Lech as far as I can see it's formatted just fine. What issue do you have with it?

Comment: @Gili in Java we don't put a new line before the opening curly bracket like we do for C++ or C# languages.

Comment: @AleksanderLech I've been programming in Java for over 20 years. Similar to the tab vs space debate, different people/companies use whatever formatting they see fit. My particular standard involves a newline before opening curly bracket. I do this because I feel the resulting code is more readable (the open/close brackets line up vertically). To each his own.

Comment: Well I have never seen such a formatting in Java despite I only have 15 years experience here. I advise you though to check the old java conventions document and check the JDK classes formatting :)

Comment: The accepted answer is correct if the user is comparing to strings like in their example.  If they want to compare to character sets beyond their example, then maybe a more complex solution like yours would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing an exercise in my book and the exercise said, "Make a method that tests to see if the end of a string ends with 'ger.' Write the code to where it tests for any combination of upper-case and lower-case letters in the phrase 'ger.'"

So, basically, it asked me to test for a phrase within a string and ignore the case so it doesn't matter if letters in "ger" are upper or lower-case. Here is my solution:

```
package exercises;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class exercises
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input, message = "enter a string. It will"
                                + " be tested to see if it "
                                + "ends with 'ger' at the end.";



    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);

    boolean yesNo = ends(input);

    if(yesNo)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "yes, \"ger\" is there");
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\"ger\" is not there");
}

public static boolean ends(String str)
{
    String input = str.toLowerCase();

    if(input.endsWith("ger"))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

}

as you can see from the code, I simply converted the string that a user would input to all lower-case. It would not matter if every letter was alternating between lower and upper-case because I negated that.